# FileStream Attachment To Email C#

Tags: c#, email, attachment, mailkit

I wrote a code to make attachments for email sending, but I cannot understand how to make it not only for txt files. I know that all the binary files are broken because of "File.OpenText" in my code. Someone can explain to me, how to make it for all files, not only for txt.

```
    public async Task<ResponseData> SendEmail(VictimData victimData, SmtpData senderData, LetterData letter)
    {
        ResponseData response = new ResponseData();
        BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
        string newAttachment = "";
        try
        {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(senderData.senderName, senderData.senderEmail));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", victimData.email));
            /*message.Bcc.Add(new MailboxAddress(senderData.senderName, senderData.senderEmail));
            message.ReplyTo.Add(new MailboxAddress(senderData.senderName, senderData.senderEmail));*/
            message.Subject = letter.subject;
            if (letter.isHtml)
            {
                bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = letter.body;
            }
            else
            {
                bodyBuilder.TextBody = letter.body;
            }

            foreach (var attachment in letter.attachment)
            {
                newAttachment = ReadAndReplaceAttachment(attachment.filePath, victimData.email, attachment.fileName);
                bodyBuilder.Attachments.Add(newAttachment);

                File.Delete(newAttachment);
                Console.WriteLine(newAttachment);
            }

            message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
            await client.SendAsync(message);
            
            response.status = true;
            response.messages = "";

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            response.messages = ex.Message;
            response.status = false;
            return response;
        }
    }
    private string ReadAndReplaceAttachment(string filePath, string email, string newFileName)
    {
        Replacer replacer = new Replacer();
        string tempFile = Path.Combine(Helpers.tempPath, replacer.DoReplace(newFileName, email));//Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        string contentResult = "";

        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath))
        {
            contentResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
            contentResult = replacer.DoReplace(contentResult, email);
            sr.Close();
        }

        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(tempFile, true))
        {
            tw.Write(contentResult);
        }

        return tempFile;
    }
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Here is sample of a Mime Attachment.  A MIME starts with two dashes on a new line.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change your code to only call your `ReadAndReplaceAttachment()` method for txt files and not for any other type of file. For non-text files, you would just attach the original file referenced by `attachment.filePath`.